# How to create an activity log in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an Activity log section in Angular 6.  The section should show all activity any user performs (e.g if a user creates a comment, adds something to the site or delete or edits comment) and I do not know how to achieve this.

Please can someone help me with a basic way to achieve this and I can work my way from there? I am new to Angular

Comment: you can use LocalStorage if you don't want to use a Db in the BE. you have to hard code the action to add the 'action the user performed' in every part you want the action to be registered. After that, the component that show the log just cycle the item you've added in the localStorage and you're up to go. Otherwise witha db is more easy. Simply do an http.post when the user do an action and at app-loading retrieve the data.

Comment: okay thank you Jacopo Sciampi

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, you should not even consider storing that data client-side, because it's pointless. Why do you need eventlog on clientside? It's useless for you, because you as a developer, has no access to that. All that actions should be stored by your backend (I believe you have backend, because without backend there is no point of having any comments section).

Comment: yes I have backend. Thank you for the clarity friend